# C++ Custom User Defined Main?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I am very confused by this code given to us:

```
class KeyedWord
{
public:
    KeyedWord(char* word); // TO BE IMPLEMENTED
    char* getWord(); // TO BE IMPLEMENTED
    char* getKey();  // TO BE IMPLEMENTED
    ~KeyedWord();
private:
    char * _word;
    char* _key;
};
void main(int argumentCount, char** arguments)
{
    if (argumentCount <= 1) 
    {
        std::cout << "No file name given as argument" << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
}
```

I am confused because:

how am I supposed to provide an overload to main if the main is the origin of the program?

Also, when I try to implement the one of the functions above I get an error telling me there is a definition error.  This is what I am trying:

```
void KeyedWord::getWord()
{

    return;
}
```

Comment: an overload to `main`? o_O why would you want to do this

Comment: You *don't* override/overload `main`, you *edit* it to include the code you want (if it exist, if the `main` function doesn't exist then you create one). As for the error, please *edit your question* to include the complete error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot overload the `main` function.

From the standard:

> **3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]**
>
> 2/ An implementation shall not predefine the main function. **This function shall not be overloaded.** It shall have a return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both:
>
> - a function of () returning `int` and
> - a function of (`int`, pointer to pointer to `char`) returning `int`

---

Also you declare

```
 class KeyedWord
{
public:
    // ...
    char* getWord(); // TO BE IMPLEMENTED

    // ...
};
```

and you define the method as

```
   void KeyedWord::getWord() { ... }
// ^^^^
```

The return type is not correct...

Comment: So if this cannot be done, then why does the program execute?

Comment: @user2758770 Your program compiles?

Answer (score 0):

You can use void main(...), it's just not standard. By the way, this is overloading:

```
void func();

void func(int value);
```

and you cannot do it to the main function.

Comment: This is why I am confused.  If this cannot be done, then why does this code compile and run?  This code is from out professor and I am very confused by it.

Comment: So how do I overload the main?